# java array outofboundexception

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static int[] squeeze(int[] ints) {
    int i;
    int[] temp;
    temp = new int[100];

    for (i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
      if (ints[i] != ints[i + 1]) {
        temp[i] = ints[i];
        }
        else{
            while (ints[i] != ints[i + 1]) {
              i++;
            }
            temp[i] = ints[i];
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

When I run this code, it gives me arrayOutOfBoundException. Can any body point the error? I am basically checking that no two consecutive numbers in an array are the same and then printing the same array but with a copy of the next number if two consecutive are same.

Comment: the ints[i+1] in the last iteration

Comment: for loop `i< ints.length-1`. Since you are checking ith with ith+1

Comment: now its giving me an array dump something but the outofboundException is gone.

Comment: In your if statement, when running through the last instance of the while loop you check to see if it's grater than i+1, and there is nothing in the position of i+1 in the array, causing the exception. Test to make sure you're not at the end of the array, before checking if the next is equal to the previous.

Answer (score 1):

When

```
i == ints.length-1
```

the check

```
ints[i] != ints[i + 1]
```

will give an error since

```
ints[i + 1]
```

does not exist.

`array.length` gives the number of elements in the array, while the index of the array starts at 0, not at 1. So the element of an array `array[array.length]` will never exist and will always give an exception.